# Wide equations in enumerate

Tags: equations, lists, enumerate, multline

When inside an `enumerate` or `itemize`, I noticed that my displayed equations (most of which are pretty long) don't use the full text width, but instead are indented - due to being inside a list environment, I suppose. Is there any way that I can make my equations use the full text width so that I don't have to use `split`, `multline` or `multlined` where they're not really necessary?

If it's any help, I'm writing a proof of a theorem which has multiple parts, so inside the `proof` environment I have an `enumerate` where I prove each part separately.

Comment: Providing an MWE would be helpful and save time for those willing to help you.

Comment: the width applied to a display varies according to document class (`amsart`, for example, applies the full text width, not the narrowed width of the list text at the current level), so it would be helpful if you at least identify the document class.  (even better, of course, would the an mwe.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `enumitem`, here are four very simple possibilities to recover as much as possible of `textwidth` for equations. It uses the `wide` key, and the `*`  value for leftmargin for two of them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
\begin{enumerate}[wide]
    \item Item 1, with some text. A long item. A long item. A long item. A long item. A long item. A long item. A long item.
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{enumerate}[wide, leftmargin=*]
    \item Item 1, with some text. A long item. A long item. A long item. A long item. A long item. A long item. A long item.
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{enumerate}[wide = 0pt]
    \item Item 1, with some text. A long item. A long item. A long item. A long item. A long item. A long item. A long item.
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{enumerate}[wide = 0pt, leftmargin = *]
    \item Item 1, with some text. A long item. A long item. A long item. A long item. A long item. A long item. A long item.
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't use enumerations as sections. In your example -- you elaborate on a proof -- just use sections, subsections, subsubsections and whatever. You know that you can add more levels to the standard levels, do you?

To change the default margin of enumerations, load the paralist package and adapt to your needs: `\setdefaultleftmargin{2.5em}{2.2em}{1.87em}{1.7em}{1em}{1em}`.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting using `paralist` - that reminded me that the `enumitem` package (which I already have loaded) might have similar options, which indeed it does. So in that `\begin{enumerate}` I can simply set the left margin using an optional argument!

Answer (score 0):

So I found a good way to do it using the optional parameters to `enumerate` which are provided by the `enumitem` package. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{enumerate}[itemindent=24pt,leftmargin=0pt]
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```